# Custom domain for WordPress site hosted on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns

Here's what I have:

1. A top level domain registered with domain.com
2. A WordPress 4.5 web app hosted on Microsoft Azure

Right now I can access my WordPress site with a URL 'example'.azurewebsites.net

But I want my website to still be hosted on Azure, but accessed with 'example'.com url. Is that possible?

I tried changing "Website URL" to 'example'.com in the WordPress  settings. But that resulted in 'example'.com pointing to "This site is under development" page and 'example'.azurewebsites.net redirecting to 'example'.com .

Comment: Contact Azure to get the nameservers for their hosting server. Add the nameservers to your domain at domain.com . If more info is needed, you should open a ticket with azure / domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

custom domain name is supported only for Shared, Basic and Standard modes. Please check if you are in one of that.
Then, just adding the domain name on the portal will not work - you should create DNS record that map the domain you have to your web app.

I did not use the domain.com, but it should be similar to how it looks like with other registrars like GoDaddy - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/ is the tutorial.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I have a free plan, so I cannot do this. There is a guide for any external doman for Azure web app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/